# Reregister node routes

Tags: javascript, node.js, ejs

I wish to know whether a route once registered can be changed or not. I am having a website launched and once a request is made, I need to check whether the website is launched or not. If it is, then I want the actual website to render. Else, I need to show the coming soon page. Since, the launch is gonna happen in a live event, I need to have the value changed. So for eg, I make a request to home page, the website is not yet launched, then it should show the coming soon page and If it is, then it show the home page. Now, I have a boolean isLaunched=false initialised. As the guest launches it, I have the value changed to true and I want to render the entire website. For this I used if else conditionals - for eg:

```
if(!isLaunched){
```

...some routes that are to be used for launch page.

```
  app.get("*",function(req,res){
    res.render("coming-soon");
  });

}else{
  app.get("/",function(req,res){
    res.render("home");
  });
```

...all routes

```
}
```

Now to make this change, I have wrapped them in a function so that they can be updated.

function updateRoutes(){

```
if(!isLaunched){
```

...some routes that are to be used for launch page.

```
  app.get("*",function(req,res){
    res.render("coming-soon");
  });

}else{
  app.get("/",function(req,res){
    res.render("home");
  });
```

...all routes

```
}
```

}

So now, after I check for whether the site is launched or not, I can call this function in order to register. However this doesen't work. It still shows the coming soon page for all routes.

```
isLaunched=true;
updateRoutes();
```

Please help me with this. i ain't know why this doesen't work. Can routes be reregistered? Please suggest a possible solution.

Thank you in advance.
Have a nice day!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this, you can use a middleware that catches all requests, and then only lets the request go to its proper handler if `isLaunched` is `true`.

```js
const app = express();

app.use('*', (req, res, next) => {
    if (isLaunched || req.path === '/coming-soon') {
        return next()
    }

    res.redirect('/coming-soon')

    // You can also render if you want
    // res.render('coming-soon')
})

// Other routes here
```

### Edit

To define routes that should be accessible when `isLaunched` is true, you can just define those routes after the middleware. If you haven't called the `next()` method in the middleware, it won't go to the next handlers. So If `isLaunched` is not true, you never call `next()`

```js
app.get('/login', handler)
app.get('/register', handler)
```

So basically you know define how you would normally define a route.

### Edit 2:

If you wish to multiple routes that should be accessible if `isLaunched` is false, you can define those routes before using the middleware.

Comment: Thank you so much man! I wish to know whether I can have a couple of more routes if isLaunched is false. How can I get that to happen? Thank you again. I 'd also have a couple post routes.

Comment: @IbrahimKhalil you just add those routes before the middleware. I have updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

In Express, there is no supported way to change, edit or remove a route you have already registered.  It would be possible to do by hacking the internal (non-documented) data structures in Express.

More typically, you would just create a route handler that has its own conditional logic inside of it so the route handler decides which logic should be applied inside the route handler. So, rather than have two route handlers and switching them, you have one permanent route handler that has its own conditional logic in it to decide how to act given the current state.

If you want a route that can respond to all pages, then you would just use an `app.use()` middleware.

```
// middleware that sends coming-soon page if not launched yet
app.use(function(req, res, next){
    if (!isLaunched) {
        // don't go to any other route handlers
        res.render("coming-soon");
    } else {
        // continue processing to other route handlers
        next();
    }
});

// other routes that get hit if isLaunched is true
app.get("/",function(req, res){
    res.render("home");
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much brother. I used you advice and it works. Thank you. I'd love it if u can help me with another thing, I wish to have route handlers inside the (!isLaunched) block. So I don't want to just render the coming soon page, if it is not launched. I want to have routes such as /launch and some others which help to launch. So as a person visits any othe page if it is not launched, it should show coming soon, but a specific /launch route will render another page, which is used to change the variable.

Comment: @IbrahimKhalil - Just define those routes.  Put them before the above middleware and then use `if (!isLaunched)` inside of them also to determine what to do.

Comment: @IbrahimKhalil - If this has answered your question, then you can indicate that to the community by clicking the checkmark to the left of the answer and also earn yourself some reputation points for following the proper procedure.